# mongodb client connection takes 15 minutes in .net core when deployed on linux server but the same working fine when deployed on windows server

Tags: c#, linux, mongodb, .net-core

I have the code in .NET CORE deployed on windows works fine when c# mongo db client access the document. However when the same code is deployed on linux machine takes 15 minutes to fetch the document and it happens intermittently. I also updated the MongoDb driver to 2.10.4 but it didn't work for me.

```
// Code trying to fetch Document from web api , calling library method to fetch document 

MongoDbService _mongoDbClient = new MongoDbService(_configuration["MongoDBConnection"]);
Conversation storedmodel = new Conversation ();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        storedmodel = _mongoDbClient.GetDocumentFromConversationId(ConversationId);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (i == 9)
        {
            //Logging exception
            LumenTelemetry.TrackEvent(conversationID, " Error - " + ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////// Code in Library Project

public interface IMongoService
{
    IMongoDatabase GetDatabase(string dbName);
    Conversation GetDocumentFromConversationId(string conversationId);
}

 

public class MongoDbService : IMongoService
{
    private readonly MongoClient _mongoClient;

    public MongoDbService(string conStr)
    {
        var connection = new MongoDbConnection(conStr);
        _mongoClient = connection.MongoConnection;
    }


    public Conversation GetDocumentFromConversationId(string conversationId)
    {
        IMongoDatabase db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("ConversationDb");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Conversation>("ConversationCollection/documents");
        var document = collection.Find(doc => doc.ConversationId == conversationId).FirstOrDefault();
        return document;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any network issues with this linux machine?

Comment: Any news on this? We are facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging to troubleshoot:

- command monitoring in the driver
- look at server logs

Identify where the time is spent:

- prior to anything mongodb-related happening? (problem in your application unrelated to mongodb)
- server selection
- query write/request
- query processing on server

Play with server selection timeout, connect timeout, socket timeout & maxTimeMS to identify the cause.